# How to infer schema from Confluent Schema Registry using Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam, confluent-schema-registry, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm trying to create an Apache Beam pipeline where I read from a kafka topic and load it into Bigquery. Using Confluent's schema registry, I should be able to infer the schema when loading into Bigquery. However, the schema is not being inferred when the loading and it fails.

Below is the entire pipeline code.

```
    pipeline
        .apply("Read from Kafka",
                KafkaIO
                        .<byte[], GenericRecord>read()
                        .withBootstrapServers("broker-url:9092")
                        .withTopic("beam-in")
                        .withConsumerConfigUpdates(consumerConfig)
                        .withValueDeserializer(ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(schemaRegUrl, subj))
                        .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)
                        .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                        .withoutMetadata()

        )
        .apply("Drop Kafka message key", Values.create())
        .apply(
                "Write data to BQ",
                BigQueryIO
                        .<GenericRecord>write()
                        .optimizedWrites()
                        .useBeamSchema()
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withSchemaUpdateOptions(ImmutableSet.of(BigQueryIO.Write.SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION))
                        .withCustomGcsTempLocation("gs://beam-tmp-load")
                        .withNumFileShards(10)
                        .withMethod(FILE_LOADS)
                        .withTriggeringFrequency(Utils.parseDuration("10s"))
                        .to(new TableReference()
                                .setProjectId("my-project")
                                .setDatasetId("loaded-data")
                                .setTableId("beam-load-test")
        );
return pipeline.run();
```

When running this I get the following error, which is from the fact that i'm calling useBeamSchema() and hasSchema() returns false:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:127)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expandTyped(BigQueryIO.java:2595)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:2579)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1726)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:493)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:368)
at KafkaToBigQuery.run(KafkaToBigQuery.java:159)
at KafkaToBigQuery.main(KafkaToBigQuery.java:64)
```

Comment: title seems misleading, you're using Kafka Schema Registry, right ?

Comment: Is the subject registered with a schema?

```
https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#subjects
```

the subject by default will be 'topic-name'-'value'